# At what point does the synchronization end?

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization

I am just trying to setup my old laptop to mine just to see how it will do and I downloaded the latest version of Geth and began the sync with

"geth --rpc --fast --cache=512"

It did its thing but it does not seem to end. I am referencing https://etherscan.io/ where is shows the number now at ~38007XX the sync is at this amount and just continues to go up and not complete as more blocks continue to be completed. Have I messed something up?

Answer (score 1):

Geth will continue to sync as more blocks are created on the network, so you should see it downloading a new block every few seconds.

I might be misreading your question. If so, can you post the last few lines of your geth console output? That might clear up any misunderstandings.